# Changing object at NSMutable Array of Objects

Tags: arrays, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray (called postArray) of Objects Post.

The object Post is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface PostAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property NSInteger annotationID;
@property NSInteger postID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* profile;
@end
```

How I am going to change the value of the postArray.postID at object i?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You just change it.  If you don't have a pointer to it stashed, access the array with objectAtIndex to fetch the pointer.  Keep in mind that NS(Mutable)Array does not contain *copies* of the objects, but rather pointers to the original objects you inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to cast the object from the array:

```
((PostAnnotation*)[postArray objectAtIndex:index]).postId = 1234;
```

Otherwise, you can use this method:

```
PostAnnotation *postAnnotation = postArray[index]
postAnnotation.postId = 1234;
```

Comment: I was trying [postArray objectAtIndex:index]).postId = 1234;. Thank you very much!!